# Public CDN image not showing on the Spfx Extension Application customizer

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions, public-cdn

I have an Image using PublicCDN which is referring in my Spfx ext application customizer but some how it is not displaying the image when I deploy in App catalog.

```
<div className={`ms-bgColor-neutralLighter ms-fontColor-white ${styles.app}`}>
                <div className={`ms-bgColor-neutralLighter ms-fontColor-white ${styles.top}`}>
                        <img src="https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/test.sharepoint.com/sites/appcatalog/ClientSideAssets/Id/logo-white_14968e4062e63295121787027906bae4.png" className={styles.headerlogo}/>
                    <CommandBar
                        className={styles.commandBar}
                        {...CommandBarProps}
                        items={commandBarItems}
                       
                    />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL of the image: Ensure that the URL of the image hosted on the PublicCDN is correct and accessible. You can try accessing the image URL directly in a browser to see if it loads successfully. If the image is not accessible, it could be a problem with the URL or the hosting configuration.

Verify the permissions of the image: Check the permissions on the image file and ensure that it has appropriate permissions set for public access. If the image requires authentication or has restricted permissions, it may not be visible when the SPFx application is deployed to other sites.